# WolframAlpha function does not return structure diagram for chemicals

Tags: chemistry, wolfram-alpha-queries

Neither one of

```
WolframAlpha["Caffeine"]
WolframAlpha["Caffeine","FullOutput"]
```

returns a structure diagram for the molecule.  It's consistent since StructureDiagram is not in the list of PodIDs, but a structure diagram is returned when querying caffeine on wolframalpha.com, and when calling:

```
ChemicalData["Caffeine"]
```

Also, page 394 of the book Hands-on Start to Wolfram Mathematica (2nd edition) shows a call to WolframAlpha["caffeine"] returning a structure diagram and a 3D structure.

Anyone know why the structure diagram is missing?

Comment: `WolframAlpha["caffeine Structure diagram"]` gives it to you.

Comment: This looks like a bug, I will report it and see what I can do about it.

Comment: It's interesting that `WolframAlpha["Caffeine","Image"]` returns the expected result (in an expect unusable format).

Comment: @george2079, yes it does.  Thank you.

Comment: @bobthechemist, yes it returns an image with dimensions {540,2465}.  Not worth further processing when ChemicalData["Caffeinne","ColorStructureDiagram"] returns it explicitly.  I was most interested it finding out if something is wrong with the basic WolframAlpha[] call.  It seems like there might be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was a bug that caused some pods to show up on the web site, but not be picked up by the API that `WolframAlpha` calls.  This is fixed now,

[image]